# structs inside of list - racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a program that returns the `piece` (that its inside of a list of structs ) with higher number in both spaces (`space1` and `space2`)or in some of them
for example:

```
(define piece1 (list (make-piece 1 0) (make-piece 5 1) (make-piece 2 2) (make-piece 6 6) (make-piece 3 6)) -> return: (piece 6 6)
```

This is I have so far:

```
(define-struct piece (space1 space2)#:transparent)
(define p1  (make-piece 1 0))
(define p2  (make-piece 5 1))
(define p3  (make-piece 2 2))
(define p4  (make-piece 0 3))
(define p5  (make-piece 0 4))
(define p6  (make-piece 6 6))
(define p7  (make-piece 3 6))

(define piece1 (list p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7))
(define (higher list)
  (cond
    [(empty? list) "it don't have elements"]
    [(equal? (and(piece-space1 (first list))(piece-space2 (first list))) (and(piece-space1 (first(rest list)))(piece-space2 (first(rest list))))) (something...)]
    [(> (and(piece-space1 (first list))(piece-space2 (first list))) (and(piece-space1 (first(rest list)))(piece-space2 (first(rest list))))) (piece(first list)(higher(rest list)))]
    [else (higher(rest list))]
    )
  )
(higher piece1)
```

Can anyone help correct the errors in my code?

Comment: Hi @dian 4C, could you please be more specific on the errors you get?

Comment: Hi @Waldi, of course. The error that appears is this:
first: contract violation
  expected: (and / c list? (not / c empty?))
  given: '()
thanks for giving me your time.

Comment: The problem may be when you do `(first (rest list))` in the case where you know `list` isn't empty, but `(rest list)` might be empty

Comment: Hi, @Alex Knauth. I put that one (first (rest list)), because I got this other error  :    piece-space1: contract violation
  expected: piece?
  given: (list (piece 0 1) (piece 0 2) (piece 0 3) (piece 0 4) (piece 0 5) (piece 0 6))

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant. If `l` is a list, then `(first l)` is only valid once you know it's not empty. Likewise `(first (rest l))` is only valid once you know `(rest l)` isn't empty